# Disable flyway on quakus live reload

Tags: quarkus, flyway

I run my quarkus application using:

```
mvn compile quarkus:dev
```

I have flyway also integrated in my application. Every time my application live reloads due to some changes flyway also checks for any migration done on db. How can I disable it because it increases the live reload time.

application.yaml:

```
quarkus:
  flyway:
    migrate-at-start: false
    baseline-on-migrate: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a property available `flyway.enabled`.which is `true` by default. To disable flyway you need to make it `false`.

**Solution** **:**

```
quarkus:
  flyway:
    enabled: false
    migrate-at-start: false
    baseline-on-migrate: true
```

Comment: Also, you can make it specific to dev mode by using `%dev` as the root.